# springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException :Invalid column type-

Tags: java, sql, spring-jdbc

Hi am trying to do a QueryForInt using spring jbdc.The query returns a simple count.On execution i get springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type.
I did find similar posts and tried the suggestions but i am still stuck:(...
Any help is appreciated.

```
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    params.addValue(DAOConstants.PROD_ID, custVo.getProdId(),OracleTypes.NUMBER);
    params.addValue(DAOConstants.REQ_IND,  DAOConstants.FLAG_Y,OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
```

The query:

```
  select count(1) from prod where prod_id = :PROD_ID and req_ind =:REQ_IND
```

Table definition

```
   Name              Null     Type         
   ----------------- -------- ------------ 
   PROD_ID           NOT NULL NUMBER(5)          
   REQ_IND                    VARCHAR2(10)
```

The Logs..

```
  Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; 
uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select count(1) from prod where prod_id = :PROD_ID and req_ind = :REQ_IND ]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:636)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:665)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:673)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:728)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:744)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForInt(JdbcTemplate.java:775)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:7937)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:7517)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8174)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8155)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:230)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.setObject(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:724)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:351)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:46)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:641)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:586)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: What are the types of the arguments you are putting into MapSqlParameterSource?

Comment: @geoand... thanks for the reply I tested with one argument at a time and found that the exception occurs for the argument ":PROD_ID". In MapSqlParameterSource i am inserting type int for :PROD_ID..cudnt figure out the cause.

Comment: Maybe the int is too big for the database to handle. I saw it's type is NUMBER(5), that means that it can only hold 5 digits

Comment: The problem was i forgot to use namedjdbctemplate and used simplejdbc instead.It is resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the stacktrace it looks like you are using the JdbcTemplate class. Since you are using the named parameter style place holders and providing a MapSqlParameterSource for the parameters you need to use the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

So, why are you getting this strange error message? Well, your SQL query actually works using the Oracle JDBC driver. It does allow you to use either "?" or a named parameter style using a ":" as the prefix fro the placeholders. You still need to provide the parameter values in the correct order which the MapSqlParameterSource in your case does not. You can test this by using an Object array instead like:

```
new Object[] {custVo.getProdId(), DAOConstants.FLAG_Y}
```

The error is based on the values coming in the wrong order from the params.getValues() method, with the String value being passed in for the :PROD_ID.

Comment: Are u suggesting that the order of parameters in map SQL parameters should match with the order they are referred to in query?

Comment: Only if you are _not_ using the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate support for named placeholders. If you use a plain JdbcTemplate the parameter order must match the order of the placeholders.

Comment: Hello everyone, I am getting same method but launching a query like this: "select max(column_name) from table. In DBeaver result is what I expected but with jdbcTemplate I get this error: Column 'column_name' not found. Any suggestions? Appreciated.